# while we click on radio button. the value which we get in radio button based on that value i want to show template

Tags: html, vue.js

while we click on radio button. After clicking the radio button we will gat an value suppose if we click on radio button then we will get "IT" so based on that IT I want to show  a template which contains "v-if = 'category==IT'". So How to achieve this please help me. So based on the radio button value i want to display the template

```
<template v-if="">

                    <h1 class="preview_adttl">Consumer<% this.category %></h1>
                    <input type="radio" @change="selectComp" v-model="category">
                    <label style="position: relative;left: 1px;" class="personal_postad">Personal Ad:</label>
                    <p class="postad_p">Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear <br>
                        with "sale by owner
                        tag"</p><br>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;"
                                @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()"
                                class="btn btn-primary">Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>
```

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="postad_fieldset" v-if="step == 1">
            <a href="/home" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-right: 5px;" type="button">×</a>
            <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;height: 440px;">
                <p class="progress_bar1"></p>
                <p class="progress_percent1"></p>
                <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                <p><input class="vue_input" style="width: 93%;" type="text" v-model="category"
                          placeholder="Search your category"
                          name="category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type" required></p>

                <p>
                    <input style="width: 93%;"class="vue_input" placeholder="Title" type="text" v-model="title" name="title" maxlength="60"
                           id="id_post_title">
                </p>

                <p class="select_p">
                    <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Address" v-model="address" name="address"
                           maxlength="200" id="id_post_address">
                    <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="City" v-model="city" name="city" maxlength="100"
                           id="id_post_city">
                </p>

                <p class="select_p">
                    <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="State" v-model="state" name="state"
                           maxlength="100" id="id_post_state">
                    <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Zip" v-model="zip" name="zip" maxlength="50"
                           id="id_post_zip">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input class="vue_input" style="width: 93%;" type="number" placeholder="Price" v-model="price"
                           name="price" step="any" id="id_post_price">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <textarea style="height: 100px;padding-left: 9px;" class="vue_input" name="description"
                              v-model="description" placeholder="Ad description.." rows="5" maxlength="600"
                              id="id_post_description"></textarea>
                </p>
                <button class="step1_next" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset class="postad_fieldset progress_bar2" v-if="step == 2">
            <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;">
                <!--if we enter category 'Real Estate | Single Family Homes' in first screen at category field. If that entered category and this template
                is matched then based on that category we are prompting this template -->
                {% if user_type == 'business' %}
                <template v-if="category == 'Real Estate | Single Family Homes'">
                    <p class="progress_bar1"></p>
                    <p class="progress_percent1"></p>

                    <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bedrooms" name="bedrooms_p"
                               v-model="bedrooms" id="id_post_bedrooms">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Bathrooms" name="bathrooms_p"
                               v-model="bathrooms" id="id_post_bathrooms">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="SQFT" name="Square_ft_p" v-model="Square_ft"
                               maxlength="100" id="id_post_Square_ft">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Lot size" name="lot_size_p"
                               v-model="lot_size" maxlength="50" id="id_post_lot_size">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Total rooms" v-model="total_rooms"
                               name="total_rooms_p" id="id_post_total_rooms">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Stories" name="stories_p" v-model="stories"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_stories">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Year built" v-model="year_built"
                               name="year_built_p" id="id_post_year_built">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="HOA" name="h_o_a_p" v-model="h_o_a"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_h_o_a">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Garages" name="garages_p" v-model="garages"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_garages">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Basement" name="basement_p" v-model="basement"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_basement">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Roof" name="roof_p" v-model="roof"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_roof">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Exterior" name="exterior_p" v-model="exterior"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_Exterior">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Cooling" name="cooling_p" v-model="cooling"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_cooling">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Heating" name="heating_p" v-model="heating"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_heating">
                    </p>

                    <!-- Select drop down list for schools based on state and city we prompt near by schools in drop down list dynamically. Multiple selection.-->

                    <p>
                        <select class="vue_input" style="width: 93%;" placeholder="Schools" name="schools_p"
                                v-model="schools" id="id_post_schools"></select>
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image_p" v-model="image" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image2_p" v-model="image2" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image2">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image3_p" v-model="image3" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image3">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image4_p" v-model="image4" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image4">
                    </p>
                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()"
                                class="btn btn-info">Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()"
                                class="btn btn-primary">Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>

                <!--                      -->
                <template v-else-if="category == 'laptop'">
                    <p class="progress_bar1"></p>
                    <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                    <h2> laptop template</h2>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()"
                                class="btn btn-info">Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()"
                                class="btn btn-primary">Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>

                <template v-else-if="category == 'computer'" v-show="x == 'one'">
                    <p class="progress_bar1"></p>
                    <h1 class="preview_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                    <h2> computer template</h2>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>

                <template v-else-if="category == 'IT'">
                    <div style="height: 326px;">
                        <p style="position:relative;left: 107px;" class="progress_bar1"></p>
                        <p style="width: 190px;" class="progress_percent1"></p>
                        <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                        <p class="select_p">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title_it" v-model="title_it"
                                   maxlength="200" id="id_post_title_it">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Experience" name="experience_it"
                                   v-model="experience" maxlength="200" id="id_post_experience_it">
                        </p>

                        <p class="select_p">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location_it"
                                   v-model="location" maxlength="200" id="id_post_location_it">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Salary" name="salary_it" v-model="salary"
                                   maxlength="200" id="id_post_salary_it">
                        </p>

                        <p class="select_p">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Industry" name="industry_it"
                                   v-model="industry" maxlength="200" id="id_post_industry_it">
                            <input class="vue_input" type="text" name="time_it" v-model="time" maxlength="200"
                                   id="id_post_time_it">
                        </p>

                        <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image_p" v-model="image" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image2_p" v-model="image2" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image2">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image3_p" v-model="image3" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image3">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image4_p" v-model="image4" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image4">
                    </p>


                        <p class="prev_next">
                            <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">
                                Previous
                            </button>
                            <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Next
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <template v-else-if="category == 'Boat'">
                    <h1 class="preview_adttl">Post Ad</h1>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="number" placeholder="Year" name="Yearofmake"
                               id="id_post_year_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Make" name="Make" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_make_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Model" name="Model" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_model_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Type" name="type_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_type_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Class" name="class_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_class_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Length" name="length_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_length_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Beam" name="beam_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_beam_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Draft" name="draft_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_draft_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Weight" name="weight_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_weight_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Engine" name="engine_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_engine_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="HP" name="hp_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_hp_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Drive" name="drive_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_drive_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Fuel Type" name="fuel_type_boat"
                               maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_fuel_type_boat">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Status" name="status_boat" maxlength="200"
                               id="id_post_status_boat">
                    </p>
                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="text" placeholder="Condition" name="condition_boat"
                               maxlength="200" id="id_post_condition_boat">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image_p" v-model="image" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image2_p" v-model="image2" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image2">
                    </p>

                    <p class="select_p">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image3_p" v-model="image3" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image3">
                        <input class="vue_input" type="file" name="image4_p" v-model="image4" accept="image/*"
                               id="id_post_image4">
                    </p>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>
                {% else %}
                <template v-if="">

                    <h1 class="preview_adttl">Consumer<% this.category %></h1>
                    <input class="consumer_radio" type="radio" id="consumer" name="flag"  @change="selectComp" v-model="category">
                    <label style="position: relative;left: 1px;" class="personal_postad">Personal Ad:</label>
                    <p class="postad_p">Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear <br>
                        with "sale by owner
                        tag"</p><br>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;border-color:lightgray;"
                                @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;border-color:#01ABBAA;" @click.prevent="next()"
                                class="btn btn-primary">Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </template>

                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset class="postad_fieldset" v-if="step == 3">

            <div style="width: 100%;position: relative;left: 12px;height: 246px;">
                {% if user_type == 'business' %}
                <template v-if="">
                    <p style="position:relative;left: 216px;" class="progress_bar1"></p>
                    <p style="width: 300px;" class="progress_percent1"></p>
                    <h1 class="post_adttl">Package</h1>
                    <div style="position: relative;top: -26px;">
                    <p>
                        <input style="width: 4%;" type="radio" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1"
                               value="$4.99 - 12 Ads - Month"><span
                            class="radio_price1"> $2.99 - 6 Ads/Month</span>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <input style="width: 4%;" class="price2" type="radio" v-model="radio_price2" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1"
                               value="$4.99 - 12 Ads - Month"><span
                            class="radio_price2" style="position: relative;
    top: -13px;"> $4.99 - 12 Ads/Month</span>
                    </p>

                    <p style="margin-top: -30px;">
                        <input style="width: 4%;" type="radio" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1"
                               value="$8.99 - 24 Ads - Month"><span
                            class="radio_price3"> $8.99 - 24 Ads/Month</span>
                    </p>

                    <p style="margin-top: -20px;">
                        <input style="width: 4%;" type="radio" name="price_Ads_package" class="price_1"
                               value="Need More"><span
                            class="radio_price4"> Need More (Contact us)</span></p>
                    </p>

                    <p class="prev_next">
                        <button style="background-color: lightgray;" @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-info">
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button style="background-color: #01ABAA;" @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Next
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </template>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

                </template>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
   var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
            step:1,
           category: '',
           title:'',
           address:'',
           city:'',
           state:'',
           zip:'',
           price:'',
           description:'',

           bedrooms:'',
           bathrooms:'',
           Square_ft:'',
           lot_size:'',
           total_rooms:'',
           stories:'',
           year_built:'',
           h_o_a:'',
           garages:'',
           basement:'',
           roof:'',
           exterior:'',
           cooling:'',
           heating:'',
           price_Ads_package:'',
           radio_price2:'',
           picked:''
       },

       // By using this delimiters we were able to fix the vue.js compatibility with django. since the curly braces between django and
    // vue.js conflicted, delimiters helped here to solve the conflicts
       delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
        ready: function() {
        console.log('ready');
    },

//This method is used for preview button while we click on preview we will navigate to previous screen-->
   methods:{
       prev() {
           this.step--;
       },

//By using next method user will able to navigate at next screen
       next() {
           this.step++;
       },
       selectComp: function ( event ) {
          console.log(this.category);
        },
        submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"step1_category":this.category, "step1_title":this.title,
                "step1_address":this.address,
                "step1_city": this.city,
                "step1_state": this.state,
                "step1_Zip": this.zip,
                "step1_price": this.price,
                "step1_description": this.description,
                "step2_bedrooms_p": this.bedrooms,
                "step2_bathrooms_p": this.bathrooms,
                "step2_Square_ft_p": this.Square_ft,
                "step2_lot_size_p": this.lot_size,
                "step2_total_rooms_p": this.total_rooms,
                "step2_stories_p": this.stories,
                "step2_year_built_p": this.year_built,
                "step2_h_o_a_p": this.h_o_a,
                "step2_garages_p": this.garage,
                "step2_basement_p": this.basement,
                "step2_roof_p": this.roof,
                "step2_exterior_p": this.exterior,
                "step2_cooling_p": this.cooling,
                "step2_heating_p": this.heating,
                "price_Ads_package": this.price_Ads_package},//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },


   }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Simple v-if is not working for you?

Comment: <template v-if = "category=='IT'" ></template>

Comment: Since your input type radio have v-model bind with category variable I don't think it should be any issue. You may need to add value to your input value="IT"

Comment: yeh I have tried with binding binding like this "v-model = 'category' " but still it is not working

Comment: Define v-if as `v-if="category === 'IT'"`.

Comment: yes I have define v-model="category" at radio button and the template which i need to call there i have defined  v-if="category === 'IT'" and it is not working